# EL custom function, how to declare HashSet<Integer> in <function-signature>?

Tags: jsp, generics, el, taglib

I'm looking for a solution with a custom function in EL.

Below, the **.tld** file :

```
<function>
    <description>
        Retourne vrai si l'élement est contenu dans la collection, faux sinon.
    </description>
    <name>isIn</name>
    <function-class>com.plebicom.librairies.ebuyclub.partenaire.Partenaire</function-class>
    <function-signature>
        boolean isIn(HashSet<Integer> partenairesExclus, int idPart)
    </function-signature>
</function>
```

Then, the **.java** file :

```
public static boolean isIn(HashSet<Integer> partenairesExclus, int idPart) {

    if(partenairesExclus.contains(idPart)) {

        return true;

    }

    return false;

}
```

When I try to compile it, an error occurs :

> The tag "</Integer>" is missing.

So I try to use > and < instead of "<" and ">". But that doesn't works.

Maybe someone know a solution to fix it.

In advance, thanks !

Comment: Not sure you specified UTF-8 charset in tld definition

Answer (score 1):

Function signatures in taglib doesn't support generics in first place. You can safely keep out it.

I gather that your concrete problem for which you possibly incorrectly thought that declaring the generic type would be correct solution, is that the function couldn't be found. But this is actually because you didn't declare classes by FQN (Fully Qualified Name), thus including the package. In other words, you must declare `HashSet` as `java.util.HashSet` and omit the argument names.

Below is the proper declaration:

```
<function-signature>
    boolean isIn(java.util.HashSet, int)
</function-signature>
```

Comment: It works for me. Please tell how your setup and environment is different from bare defaults and currently available versions.

Comment: `[EBC] - 2016-07-22 14:33:44,128 ERROR ActionBeanSupport:108 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The class java.util.HashSet partenairesExclus specified in the method signature in TLD for the function fnc:isIn cannot be found.` And I guess my environment is the default one.

Comment: Right, you included argument variable names as well. You should not do that in method signatures. Sorry that I didn't spot this mistake sooner, I have updated the answer on this.